# Sort list and return original index

Tags: c#, sorting

I need to sort a list "angle" containing doubles and as a result i want to return the original index.

I tried this with Linq but the index doesn't match the sort

```
var sorted = angle
    .Select((x, i) => new KeyValuePair<double, int>(x, i))
    .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
    .ToList();

List<int> idx = sorted.Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

The results what I want from idx: 
[2,4,5,1,3,0,7,6]
but I get: [4,3,0,6,7,1,5,2]

[image]
left the unsorted angles and right the wrong sort of index values as result

Comment: What exactly is `angle` here? If it is a list of doubles containing the values in the left hand list, your code will give you the results you expect.

Comment: Can you show how  `angle` is populated? Do you `double.Parse()` strings with commas for that? (Hard to tell from your screenshot). The commas might be seen as group separators not the decimal point and hence been ignored.

Comment: angle is my list of doubles. So i don't know why the sorting is wrong

Comment: angles is the result from a vector calculation. "double riAng = angle2 * 180 / (Math.PI)" is added to a List<double> called angle

Comment: Show the contents of the list, there is something wrong about your assumptions here.

Comment: Your code is definitly working: https://dotnetfiddle.net/1sWkfk Your data must be deviating, from what you  expect.

Comment: It's working i did something wrong with the angle list